# How to solve horizontal scroll on Django admin pages

Tags: django

The problem is that on pages with long text in some fields list table becomes too wide and there is only one way to scroll it - you have to scroll to the bottom where you will find horizontal scroller. So if you need to see something on the right of the first row you will scroll down, right and back to top. This is very annoying.

Is there a way to avoid scrolling without truncating data?
Is there a way to add horizontal another scroller on top of the table?

Answer (score 0):

You can override and extend the basic Django admin templates and change the design the way you want it to. There is no out-of-the-box solution for your problem in Django itself but you can check out external libraries.